# Removing Empty Lines from adding items in listbox

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am adding lines from a file to a listbox and want to remove any empty lines:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Split(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(logsFilePath & "GENERAL.LOG"), vbNewLine), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

The above code does not work, when I use `, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, it adds items to the listbox and the empty lines are also added.

I would want to have all blank lines ignored when adding items to the listbox

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And what is the that you want us to do by looking at your code? Is there an issue you are facing? Some more detail would be useful

Comment: `ListBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadLines(path).Where(Function(l)Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)).ToArray())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the lines as separate lines (there is a function to do that).

Select the none-emptylines using Linq.

Add those to the Listbox.

(extra tip: Try to avoid one-liners)

```
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(path)
Dim noneEmptyLines = lines.Where(Function(line) Not [String].IsNullOrWhitespace(line)).ToArray()
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(noneEmptyLines)
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative and a single line solution, you should do it this way:

```
 ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllText("D:\abc.txt").Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

This solution will also work for the framework(s) that does not support LINQ.